# Brew Install Watchman Failing to Install

Tags: homebrew, watchman

Im trying to install watchman and getting an error:

```
 % brew install watchman
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/watchman-4.9.0_5.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/rrr/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/00fcf18c3281f74e9d0d26d06cadff73247636ac12cfcb1f2612a14572413ac2--watchman-4.9.0_5.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring watchman-4.9.0_5.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall watchman`
```

I tried `brew postinstall watchman` and I get

```
% brew postinstall watchman
==> Postinstalling watchman
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall watchman`
```

Im on MacOS Catalina version 10.15.7

Comment: It installed OK for me (same macOS 10.15.7, watchman 4.9.0_5, brew 2.5.12). Can you uninstall it then try installing again with `--verbose` option?